# How can I make three containers grow at the same size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I am building a 3 column preview card using HTML, CSS and FLEXBOX. I built it using the mobile-first approach. It starts off as a column but when it is being expanded and it reaches a certain dimension, it transforms into a row. The problem I am having is that as the containers transform to a row, they grow in different sizes. The heights grow differently as some become columns become taller than others. How can I make sure they all grow at the same rate? How do I make sure that one column does not become larger than the other as they are being expanded? I tried setting flex-grow to 1 and flex-shrink to 1 but it is not working. Please find relevant parts of my code below.

[Here is a link to the live version of my site](https://praisepelumi.github.io/3-column-preview-card/)

```
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

--The panel is the container as a whole--
.panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    height: 100%
    
}
--I am styling each column below--
.panel  section {  
    display: flex;
    padding: 2.5rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 100%;
    
@media only screen and (min-width: 560px) {
    .panel {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        border-radius: 10px ;
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;

    }

    .panel  section {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `height: 100%` from the child elements and just simply change the `align-items` to `stretch` on desktop, that will create equal height columns.

Answer (score 0):

Well there can be different ways to solve this.

**Problem :** Due to which this error occur . It the difference between the amount of content in three containers as middle has more content that is you have told more about SUVS . This is the cause

**Solution :**  Either you can make the content almost equal or can make the height of container bigger so that content can easily fit

- Content equal and Content fixed height - Less compatible as content can vary on need
- Increase height of container - Using hard code(400px; 30em) you can increase the height of the container according to need of content . And you can position **Learn more** btn at bottom using `absolute` position . So that it positioned at equal height

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 560px)
.panel section {
    height: 30em;
    position: relative;
}
```

```
.general-button {
    background-color: var(--major-color);
    border-radius: 5rem;
    padding: 0.89rem;
    margin: 1.1em 0;
    border: none;
    width: 8rem;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```